# Primefaces 5.1 sort doesn't work with binding attribute

Tags: primefaces

I have upgraded my application to primefaces 5.1 and my below code started throwing NPE if I use binding attribute with datatable. Do anyone have any idea why after up gradation to new primefaces version I am getting Null pointer exception if I clicks on sort icon to sort the data.

xhtml code

```
<h:body>
<h:form id="dataForm">   

<p:dataTable id="datatableId" value="#{bean.listToDisplay}" var="list" widgetVar="datatableVar" binding="#{bean.dataTable}">
<p:column id="titleColumn" filterBy="#{list.title}" sortBy="#{list.title}" headerText="Title" filterMatchMode="contains">
   #{list.title}
</p:column>
</p:dataTable>
</h:form>   
</h:body>
</html>
```

The following exception I am getting

```
SEVERE: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.findColumn(DataTable.java:785)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.SortFeature.decode(SortFeature.java:85)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.decode(DataTableRenderer.java:62)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.decode(UIComponentBase.java:789)
at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processDecodes(UIData.java:246)
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:534)
at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:692)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1663)
at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1663)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1663)
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:383)
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:257)
at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:60)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my own experimentation after encountering the same problem, I have discovered that putting the `DataTable` object in a `@RequestScoped` managed bean seems to solve the problem.

This can include either changing the managed bean to `@RequestScoped`, if possible, and if this is not possible, create a separate `@RequestScoped` bean that includes the `DataTable`.